# How to fix Content Security Policy error Node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, content-security-policy

```
const express = require('express');
const graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql');
const schema = require('./schema/schema');

const app = express();

app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
   schema,
   graphiql: true,
}));

app.listen(5000, () => {
   console.log('now listening for requests on port 5000')
})
```

GET http://localhost:5000/ 404 (Not Found)

localhost/:1 Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:5000/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

[image]I'm getting a "content security policy error on my node app. I'm only running a simple node server app. I added a favicon.ico image in the root folder as per the error message request , but it doesn't go away. [image: iamge show]

Comment: You need to share your server code or we don't know what it's actually doing.

Comment: `const express = require('express');
const graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql');
const schema = require('./schema/schema');

const app = express();

app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
   schema,
   graphiql: true,
}));

app.listen(5000, () => {
   console.log('now listening for requests on port 5000')
})`

Comment: Can you edit your question to contain the code so it's more readable?

Comment: @Jacob, thank you , let me edit the question or add a screenshot of the code

Comment: Please put the code in there, not a screenshot. Also, posting the _text_ of the error message rather than a screenshot of the error makes it searchable so others with the same error can find your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An express server doesn't automatically serve up files in your source directory. If you want requests to `/favicon.ico` to serve up your file, you'll need to add the appropriate logic to your server:

```
const path = require('path');

app.get('/favicon.ico', (req, res) => {
  // Use actual relative path to your .ico file here
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../favicon.ico'));
});
```

Comment: tried that , but doesn't make a difference; thank you though

Comment: Do you see the `.ico` file getting downloaded when the browser requests `/favicon.ico`?

Comment: it shows (blocked: csp) in the network tab of chrome dev tools